# How to associate Elastic IP and NAT Gateway in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'd like to request some help about Associating Elastic IP and NAT Gateway in boto3.

## Allocate a new Elastic IP Address

eip = client.allocate_address(Domain='vpc')

## Create NAT Gateway and Allocate to Elastic IP

nat_gw = client.create_nat_gateway(SubnetId=subnet1.id,AllocationId=eip.id)

> > > eip = ec2_client.allocate_address(Domain='vpc')
> > >       ec2_client.create_nat_gateway(SubnetId=subnet1.id,AllocationId=eip.id)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a dict, wouldn't you do this?

```
nat_gw = client.create_nat_gateway(SubnetId=subnet1['id'],AllocationId=eip['id'])
```

**I'm assuming that both `subnet1` and `eip` are dicts.

I can't verify that you are doing this correctly, but the above should resolve the error you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got manage to solve this way. ( But that is not the way I prefer )

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="eu-west-2")
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name="eu-west-2")
vpc = ec2.create_vpc(CidrBlock='10.10.0.0/16')
subnet1 = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock='10.10.1.0/24',AvailabilityZone='eu-west-2a')
subnet1.meta.client.modify_subnet_attribute(SubnetId=subnet1.id, MapPublicIpOnLaunch={"Value": True})

eip_for_nat_gateway = ec2_client.allocate_address(Domain='vpc')
>>> a = client.describe_addresses()
>>> for b in a['Addresses']:
...print b['AllocationId']
eipalloc-3790c652
>>> c= b['AllocationId']
>>> print c
eipalloc-3790c652

#Now I assign c as AllocationId
nat_gw = client.create_nat_gateway(SubnetId=subnet1.id,AllocationId=c)
```